# ByteArray in c++

Tags: c#, c++-cli

In C# to send the post data(WebRequest) I used this code:

```
string postData = "username=" + UsernameInput.Text + "&password=" + PasswordInput.Text;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

How do I import this code to c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying to put the answer which you have actually put with the question(So that it may help someone in future):-

```
String^ postData = "username=" + UsernameInput->Text + "&password=" + PasswordInput->Text;
array<Byte>^byteArray = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(postData);
```

Answer (score 0):

std::string is also a container so :

```
std::string postData = ... ;
std::vector<std::string::value_type> bytes( postData.begin(), postData.end() );
```

That's all.